# how to use imagettfbox() in Imagick?

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I was family with GD of any image processing. But I just change to use Imagick because it's faster than GD. But I don't know how to use `imagettfbox` (GD) to `Imagick`.

Please help me with example or method of it ^_^

Comment: @jedifans Considering that the function you linked is part of the GD library rather than imagick, I would assume not.

Comment: Apologies, misread the question. This appears to return the bounding box of a  character: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php

Comment: @Jon : I thought it is not what i want. but after think about some algorithm of this method `queryFontMetrics` It's work for me :D
@jedifans : thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer from the comment above:
This appears to return the bounding box of a character: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php